Why I am not able to call Azure OpenAI chatbot by using this code which is provided in documentation?
I got "Error code: 404 - {'error': {'code': '404', 'message': 'Resource not found'}}" even if I have provided everything correctly. The problem for sure is not related with providing wrong Endpoints or Keys etc. I have installed "pip install openai==1.13.3"
and I have tried previous versions too, but nothing worked. I would be grateful if somebody can help.
import os
import json
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Add OpenAI import
from openai import AzureOpenAI

def main(): 
        
    try:
        # Flag to show citations
        show_citations = False

        # Get configuration settings 
        load_dotenv()
        azure_oai_endpoint = os.getenv("AZURE_OAI_ENDPOINT")
        azure_oai_key = os.getenv("AZURE_OAI_KEY")
        azure_oai_deployment = os.getenv("AZURE_OAI_DEPLOYMENT")
        azure_search_endpoint = os.getenv("AZURE_SEARCH_ENDPOINT")
        azure_search_key = os.getenv("AZURE_SEARCH_KEY")
        azure_search_index = os.getenv("AZURE_SEARCH_INDEX")
        
        # Initialize the Azure OpenAI client
        client = AzureOpenAI(
            base_url=f"{azure_oai_endpoint}/openai/deployments/{azure_oai_deployment}/extensions",
            #base_url = f"{azure_oai_endpoint}/openai/deployments/{azure_oai_deployment}?api-version=2022-12-01",
            api_key=azure_oai_key,
            api_version="2024-02-01")

        # Get the prompt
        text = input('\nEnter a question:\n')

        # Configure your data source
        extension_config = dict(dataSources = [  
                { 
                    "type": "AzureCognitiveSearch", 
                    "parameters": { 
                        "endpoint":azure_search_endpoint, 
                        "key": azure_search_key, 
                        "indexName": azure_search_index,
                    }
                }]
            )


        # Send request to Azure OpenAI model
        print("...Sending the following request to Azure OpenAI endpoint...")
        print("Request: " + text + "\n")

        response = client.chat.completions.create(
            model = azure_oai_deployment,
            temperature = 0.5,
            max_tokens = 1000,
            messages = [
                {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful customer assistant"},
                {"role": "user", "content": text}
            ],
            extra_body = extension_config
        )

        # Print response
        print("Response: " + response.choices[0].message.content + "\n")

        if (show_citations):
            # Print citations
            print("Citations:")
            citations = response.choices[0].message.context["messages"][0]["content"]
            citation_json = json.loads(citations)
            for c in citation_json["citations"]:
                print("  Title: " + c['title'] + "\n    URL: " + c['url'])


        
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()


Can you try with api_versionas 2023-07-01-preview?

@Farmanli Try with 2024-02-15-preview as api_version.

@Farmanli Replace the base URL as base_url = f"{azure_oai_endpoint}/openai/deployments/{azure_oai_deployment}/chat/completions?api-version=2024-02-15-preview" and try again.

I updated the base_url and the api_version as below in your code and able to run the application without any issues.
        base_url = f"{azure_oai_endpoint}/openai/deployments/{azure_oai_deployment}/chat/completions?api-version=2024-02-15-preview"
        client = AzureOpenAI(
            base_url=base_url,
            api_key=azure_oai_key,
            api_version="2024-02-15-preview")

Below is the complete code.
import os
import json
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from openai import AzureOpenAI

def main(): 
    try:
        show_citations = False
        load_dotenv()
        azure_oai_endpoint = os.getenv("AZURE_OAI_ENDPOINT")
        azure_oai_key = os.getenv("AZURE_OAI_KEY")
        azure_oai_deployment = os.getenv("AZURE_OAI_DEPLOYMENT")
        azure_search_endpoint = os.getenv("AZURE_SEARCH_ENDPOINT")
        azure_search_key = os.getenv("AZURE_SEARCH_KEY")
        azure_search_index = os.getenv("AZURE_SEARCH_INDEX")
        
        base_url = f"{azure_oai_endpoint}/openai/deployments/{azure_oai_deployment}/chat/completions?api-version=2024-02-15-preview"
        client = AzureOpenAI(
            base_url=base_url,
            api_key=azure_oai_key,
            api_version="2024-02-15-preview")

        text = input('\nEnter a question:\n')
        extension_config = dict(dataSources = [  
                { 
                    "type": "AzureCognitiveSearch", 
                    "parameters": { 
                        "endpoint":azure_search_endpoint, 
                        "key": azure_search_key, 
                        "indexName": azure_search_index,
                    }
                }]
            )

        print("...Sending the following request to Azure OpenAI endpoint...")
        print("Request: " + text + "\n")

        response = client.chat.completions.create(
            model = azure_oai_deployment,
            temperature = 0.5,
            max_tokens = 1000,
            messages = [
                {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful customer assistant"},
                {"role": "user", "content": text}
            ],
            extra_body = extension_config
        )
        print("Response: " + response.choices[0].message.content + "\n")

        if (show_citations):
            print("Citations:")
            citations = response.choices[0].message.context["messages"][0]["content"]
            citation_json = json.loads(citations)
            for c in citation_json["citations"]:
                print("  Title: " + c['title'] + "\n    URL: " + c['url'])
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()

Output :
The following code ran successfully as below.


For me it did not work, I do not understand why.

@Farmanli Are you still facing the same issue?

Yes, exactly the same

@Farmanli Check the ai and search details are correct or not in your code.

Thank you for answers but non of them worked for me.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
